# BlueStacks on Mac is stuck

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, bluestacks

I am trying to run BlueStacks on my Mac OS X Yosemite. After installing when I tried to open It finished loading and show me the playlist. That's it. After that it does not response at all, even the minimise button does not work.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound Yes I use official android emulator and know about Genymotion but I need to solve this issue with blueStacks. If you can please help me with that. Do not spam please.

Comment: after years it still gets stuck...unbelievable